# Kaizala API: Sending message to member

Tags: c#, kaizala

I am working on a replacement for our SMS server and, since we have O365, I am looking to use Kaizala to facilitate this.

You can target users via mobile numbers who are subscribed, so we can use the current SMS backend without much modification. Sending messages to specific subscribers is working, BUT I can't send a message targeting my number.

I am the creator of the group and so I am seen as a "Member" and not a "Subscriber". When I try to send a message via the API to my number it says "No valid subscriber found!" (that is a copy and paste from VS). I have googled and looked at a few sites, but they all only focus on the part of the code that is working.

I have tried adding myself as a subscriber, but I get an error so not sure if that is an system problem or a me problem. :)

I am also on the standby rotation, so when it is my turn for standby the SMS's need to come to me. I am hoping someone can give me a nudge in the right direction!

TIA

PS:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using RestSharp;
```